# Nsis installer get file size

Tags: installation, nsis

I am using NSIS installer.
I want to unzip file, but before, I wont to get it's size.
Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly, you can use `FileSeek` to get the position of the 0th byte from the end.

```
FileOpen $0 somefile.txt r    ;open somefile in read mode
FileSeek $0 0 END $1          ;ask for the 0th byte from the end, and put the value in $1
FileClose $0
;here you have the size in $1
```

This is used in a more convenient way that preserves the variables in the [FileSizeNew function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Getting_File_Size) that get the filename and returns the result via the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GetSize](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.3) macro, it comes pre-installed with NSIS